# Visual Studio 2013 won't sync unpushed commits to Git

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2013

"An error occurred. Detailed message: An error occurred while sending the request."
This is the error I get when trying to sync commits with server from VS.
Although, pushing to Git from command line works fine.
Tried restarting Visual Studio and reinstalled Git. Didn't help.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: May be the git executable path is not correct. Please check Visual Studio git settings

Comment: There is no git executable path setting in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: What version of Windows are you on?  Have you followed Microsoft's guidance at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/201457/unable-to-connect-to-github-due-to-tls-12-only-cha.html ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer I got from GitHub

[ Yesterday GitHub turned off TLSv1 and 1.1 in efforts to permanently deprecate several weak cryptographic standards. You could read more about that here: https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/.

To fix this issue, you should upgrade to the latest version of Visual Studio, 15.5.7- which provides support for TLSV1.2. This update allows Git to connect to services that have deprecated support for TLSv1 and TLSv1.1. ]

It looks like VS2013 is no longer supported.

This is a big problem from me because the team I am part of only has VS2013.

Comment: I am currently working with GitHub support to try and find a resolution. They suggested installing "Security Protocol Manager 2013" but I have not been successful getting that to work yet.

Comment: Have you updated your TLS 1.2 settings on Windows according to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/201457/unable-to-connect-to-github-due-to-tls-12-only-cha.html ?

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly the issue. The update to higher VS version worked.

Comment: VS2013 now works on Windows 8.1 with TLS1.2 thanks to the link posted by @EdwardThomson Make sure that the latest git client is installed as well. The issue is also relevant to Bitbucket which discontinued support for TLS 1.0/1.1 as of 1 December, 2018

Answer (score 10):

The installation of Security Protocol Manager in the VS extension did solve the problem for me by just ticking the Tls12. The image below FYI.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Some additional information relating to *Teller's* post:

I was able to download the **Security Protocol Manager** for **VS2013** [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JesseMacNett.SecurityProtocolManager2013).

After it is installed you'll want to **restart** Visual Studio.

You can access the dialog mentioned by going to **TOOLS** => **Security Protocol Manager 2013**

Comment: This solution saved me from a lot of time.